# Complex Complex Number Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

if $ \omega^{1997} = 1$ and $\omega \neq 1 $.
Evaluate
$\frac{1}{1 + \omega} + \frac{1}{1 + \omega^2} + \dots + \frac{1}{1 + \omega^{1997}}.$

Expected to be solved without the knowledge of roots of unity.
How would we solve this?

Answer (score 7):

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{1+\omega}+\frac{1}{1+\omega^{1996}}=\frac{1}{1+\omega}+\frac{\omega}{\omega+\omega^{1997}}=\frac{1+\omega}{1+\omega}=1$.
Similarly
$\displaystyle\frac{1}{1+\omega^2}+\frac{1}{1+\omega^{1995}}=
\frac{1}{1+\omega^2}+\frac{\omega^2}{\omega^2+\omega^{1997}}=\frac{1+\omega^2}{1+\omega^2}=1$
and so on. There are $1996/2$ such pairs and the initial $\dfrac{1}{1+\omega^{1997}}=\dfrac12$, so the sum equals to $1997/2$.

Comment: $$\frac1{1+\omega}+\frac1{1+\omega^{1996}}=\frac1{1+\omega}+\frac1{1+\omega^{-1}}=1$$

Comment: @Tianlalu Thank you. Corrected. (It was a mix of two different ideas).